# WPF- MessageBox to be top most

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application, i need the `MessageBox` to always be top most.
in win forms i would do something like that:

```
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(new Form() { TopMost = true }, "sure you wanna save?", "confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
```

but how do i do that in WPF?

i saw a few different answers but non of them work for me e.g:

```
MessageBox.Show(Application.Current.MainWindow, "Im always on top - of the main window");
```

My `mainWindo` is null.
In my application the `MessageBox` is opening from different pages- not windows

Any idea how i do it in the most simple way?

Comment: look into `ShowDialog()`

Comment: Displaying a dialog without an owner is a bug.  The consequence of the bug is that you can never be sure that the user actually sees the dialog, it can easily hide behind the window he's working with.  That never ends well, if you don't have a window then you must use a NotifyIcon instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will have to create your own `Window` and set its `Topmost` value to true.

```
MyWindow dialog = new MyWindow();
dialog.Topmost = true;
dialog.Show();
```

Comment: and then how do i know in the page if he pressed "ok" or "cancel"?

Comment: if you want to get the result, you should use `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()`. This displays it as modal window. In the window you can set `DialogResult` to a bool, which is returned by `ShowDialog()`

Comment: Answer provided by @George in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53009621/5868000 is working without custom windows

Answer (score 15):

Use MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly and it keeps the MessageBox on top of the window.

```
MessageBox.Show("You entered an incorrect value. Try once more.", "Wrong input", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation,MessageBoxResult.OK,MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);
```

Comment: still THE solution after five years ;)

Answer (score 6):

```
  this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
{
 MessageBox.Show("Im always on top - of the main window");
}));
```

This will run it in the UI thread.Throw this in the method that shows the msg box.

Cheers,
G

Comment: your answer doesn't make sense and doesn't work dude- a total -1

Comment: What don't you understand? You have a method to show the message box, what you need to do is invoke it in the UI thread. This will throw the box on the top most. It is actually pretty straight forward.

Comment: This method works. You might want to try Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(... rather than this.Dispatcher.Invoke

Comment: If parent window has TopMost setting that will not work. Use https://stackoverflow.com/a/53009621/5868000